# How can I correctly plot an impulse_response() of a discrete transfer function?

Tags: discrete-signals, python, impulse-response

***I posted this question on stack overflow and I think it was the wrong place so I moved it here.***

Hello, I'm new to python, I just want to use the control library and I'm slowly learning, I did my research and read the docs but as a newbie programmer I don't really understand much. I know it's about the syntax but I don't know what exactly is wrong. I'm moving from matlab to python and I can't get this to work:

```
from control import *
from sympy import *
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

Gp = tf(100,[1,0,100])
T = 0.05
Gz =sample_system(Gp, T)



x = linspace(0.0, 0.7, num=15)

T, yout = impulse_response(Gz, T=x)
plot(T, yout)
```

if I run this I get this output:

```
ValueError: Time steps ``T`` must match sampling time
```

and if I change `x = linspace(0.0, 0.7, num=15)` for `x = linspace(0.05, 0.7, num=14)` I get this:

```
ValueError: A value in x_new is below the interpolation range.
```

No idea what I'm doing wrong, I read the docs on `impulse_response()` and `linspace()`, I can't find any examples of similar problems or people plotting impulse responses using python. Thanks in advance

**Edit1:** Okay I've gotten here so far:

```
imp = signal.unit_impulse(100, 'mid')
T, yout = signal.butter(4, 0.2)
z = array([0.,0.05,0.1,0.15,0.2,0.25,0.3,0.35,0.4,0.45,0.5])
T, yout = impulse_response(Gz, T=z, input=imp)
T, yout = signal.butter(4, 0.2)
plot(T, yout)
grid(True)
show()
```

now I get a plot that looks like this:

[image]

But I need something like this:
[image]
**Edit2:** Okay seems like the whole problem was that `yout` had these dimensions: `(1,15)` and all I had to do was `.flatten()`, on the other hand I was using wrong `linspace` so I changed it for `arange`, and the end result is this:

```
Gp = tf(100,[1,0,100])
ts = 0.05
Gz =sample_system(Gp, ts)
pprint(Gz)

t = arange(0.0, 15*ts, ts)   


T, yout = impulse_response(Gz, T=t)
yout=yout.flatten()
plot(T, yout)
margins(0.1, 0.1)  
xlabel('Time [sec]') 
ylabel('Amplitude') 
grid(True) 
show()
```

and the output is:

[image]

Still seems to me that something is missing, but I don't know what, and that this is not a clean solution, anyone got a cleaner way of doing this? Having to `flatten()` seems wrong to me... in matlab you just had to `impulse(Gz, t)` and got the plot right away.

Comment: `linspace()` generates an `np.array()` object

Comment: Allright, gonna edit it, seems like I was using it wrong then, thanks.

Comment: See https://python-control.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.1/conventions.html#time-series-convention and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally this is the way I got to plot it right:

```
Gp = ct.tf(100,[1,0,100])
ts = 0.05
Gz =ct.sample_system(Gp, ts)
sym.pprint(Gz)


t = np.linspace(0,14*ts,num=15)


T, yout = ct.impulse_response(Gz, t)
yout=yout.flatten()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.step(T, yout)
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(0.05))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(0.1))
plt.margins(0.1, 0.1)
plt.title('Impulse Response c.1)')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.grid(True) 
plt.show()
```

and this is the output:

[image]

this would be the equivalent of matlab's `impulse()` in python